# Issue with Laravel Notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have a problem with Laravel notifications. I try to give a user notification about something, but Laravel cannot find notification class.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;    

class NotificationController extends Controller
{    

    public function getNot(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();            

        $user->notify(new NewPost('a'));
    }
}
```

I've also created a notification with the name `NewPost.php`, the problem is:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\NewPost' not found

this one, so in the `User` model already included `Notifications` and `notifiable.`

Comment: Please, add your notification code and the model code related to the notification.

Comment: Well in my User model ther is only  use Notifable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add use statement before class definition.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth; 
use App\Notifications\NewPost;
```

I assume that you create notification by artisan, if no, then keep in mind that namespace could be different.

Comment: i created it by artisan

Comment: stilll i've got the error  Class 'App\Notification\NewPost' not found

Comment: Notification**s** not Notification

Comment: Yeah, this is just a namespace issue.